# Jmeter Json extractor - no suffix in the variable name

Tags: json, jmeter

I am using jmeter json extractor.

In my api response I am getting values for media type as either

Case 1

```
"mediaType": {
    "__t": "MMP.Data.FieldValueCollection, MMP.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "vs": 1,
    "v": "2457cae6-6851-4471-be84-74e0ba385ded",
    "vl": "Television"
},
```

Or

Case 2

```
"mediaType": null
```

I am using json extractor to extract the value of the media plan.

Below is the screen shot of the json extractor

[image].

For the first case, I can see my variable var_1 is set to "Television" ; but for the second case, the variable name I am seeing in debug sampler is var i.e. without _1

For the second case as well, I would want my variable name to be var_1 set to null.

Is there a way I could handle this in json extractor itself?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the variable name should be the same in both the cases. If you change your "**Match No**" from **-1** to **1** in your JSON Extractor then the variable name should not contain "_1" and you will have the same name of the variable for both responses **i.e. var**

It depend on you whether to choose var or var_1 as a name for variable for further operation.

Comment: I may have mutiple values of media returned in the response, I want to store all & then iterate through them & hence I am using -1 in Match No.

Comment: Then, Check the answer provided by user7294900 and it should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If can add default value null using [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

> User Defined Variables element lets you define an initial set of variables

Just define once `var1_1` with value `null` and it will remain null in case 2 and override with `Television` in case 1.